# Eachline with textarea?

Tags: php, html

What I'm trying to do is take the text from a textarea using the `$_POST` method, and write each line with '-' at the start. This is what I got so far.

```
$lines = $_POST["textarea"];
foreach ($lines as $line)
    echo " - " . $line . "<br />\n";
```

(This is taken from [php.net](http://php.net), I haven't programmed in PHP so long) When I run it, this is all I get:

> Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   I:\xampp\htdocs\generate.php

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Probably irrelevant: You have two semicolons after `$_POST["textarea"]`

Answer (score 4):

`foreach` expects an array as its first argument. You are passing in `$lines` which is a string (possibly containing newline characters).

To process each line separately, first you have to split the input into an array of lines. You can do that with

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST["textarea"]);
```

The function [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) splits the input string into an array of substrings delimited by whatever you pass as the first parameter.

Comment: Better explanation, but I wanted to be first. You've my +1 :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how browsers submit newlines in textareas, but my guess would be that it submits them as the user's OS treats them. This means you'll have different combinations of `\r` and `\n` depending on the OS of the user. I'm not 100% sure that newlines aren't standardized when they are submitted by the browser, but it might be something you want to verify.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST["textarea"];` is no array. you have to split on the newline characters first:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']);
```